# Synchronizing Eclipse Projects

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently working on a team project in Java, using Eclipse to commit changes I make to an SVN repository. To make things safer, I actually have two versions of the Project on Eclipse: One on which I work directly, and one into which I'm supposed to copy changes made after testing. The latter is then to be committed and shared with the rest of the team.

I've done some work on the second version of the Project. Now, I want to copy all that into the first version. So, how do I synchronize two Projects on Eclipse? Copy all changes from one onto the other?

Comment: Don't think eclipse has any features for that.  You will likely have to copy each file by hand.  Why not use SVN branches to start with?  That is what the are there for...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SVN, why are you keeping duplicate copies?  SVN does this for you.  You check-out (or update, if you already have the project), then make your modifications, test them, and (assuming they test correctly) commit.  There is no reason NOT to work directly on your working copy.

If you mess up, you just use SVN to revert your changes to the last good state.

Of course if you are making major changes that could impact the whole application while at the same time doing some work on current tickets you might look into using SVN branches.

Comment: My boss felt it would be safer to have individual programmers working on a secondary version. I didn't argue. But as things stand, I have these two Projects, and I'm looking for a way to copy everything from one to the other...

Comment: It definitely isn't safer. You are trying to manually replicate precisely the work SVN was designed to do for you.